# Странный баг с мусорными строками в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, отладка

Появился ооочень странный наполовину плавающий баг с мусорными строками.

Всю архитектуру описывать очень долго, поэтому напишу вкратце, но если будет надо, обновлю вопрос с детальным описанием.

В кратце так:

создал систему для локализации игры. Есть класс `Localization` со статическими строковыми полями только для чтения, и есть файл xml со строками. Данный клас, с помощью стандартного `XmlTextReader` и рефлексии, заполняет нужные поля соответствующими значениями.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public sealed class Localization
{
    const string PATH_TO_LOCALIZATION_FILES = @"TextAssets\Localization\";
    public static SystemLanguage CurrentLanguage { get; private set; }

    #region strings;

    static public readonly string downloading;

    static public readonly string play_game;
    static public readonly string settings;
    static public readonly string squad;

    //тут еще куча static public readonly string полей 

    #endregion;


    /// <summary>
    /// Уставнавливает новый язык локализации, если для него есть определение.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="language">Новый язык локализации</param>
    /// <returns>Если язык локализации был изменен, возвратится true, иначе - false</returns>
    public static bool SetLanguage(SystemLanguage language)
    {
        SystemLanguage newLanguage;
        ReloadStrings(language, out newLanguage);

        var res = true;
        if (newLanguage == CurrentLanguage)
            res = false;
        else
            CurrentLanguage = newLanguage;

        return res;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Находит в соответствующем файле локализации нужные строки и устанавливает их значения соответствующим полям.
    /// <para>Так как не все языки поддерживаются, то загружен будет либо указанный язык, либо язык по умолчанию (английский)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="language">Язык локализации для загрузки</param>
    /// <param name="newLanguage">Сюда будет занесено значение загруженого языка локализации</param>
    static void ReloadStrings(SystemLanguage language, out SystemLanguage newLanguage)
    {
        string languageFileName = string.Empty;

        switch (language)
        {
            case SystemLanguage.Russian:
                languageFileName = "RU";
                newLanguage = SystemLanguage.Russian;
                break;
            default:
                //english
                languageFileName = "EN";
                newLanguage = SystemLanguage.English;
                break;
        }

        TextAsset localisationFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(PATH_TO_LOCALIZATION_FILES + languageFileName);
        using (TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(localisationFile.text))
        {
            using (XmlTextReader reader = XmlReader.Create(txtReader) as XmlTextReader)
            {
                while (reader.ReadToFollowing("string"))
                {
                    reader.MoveToAttribute("name");
                    var name = reader.Value;
                    reader.MoveToContent();
                    var value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

                    SetString(name, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Устанавливает значение строкового ресурса по его имени
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Имя строкового ресурса</param>
    /// <param name="value">Новое значение строкового ресурса</param>
    static void SetString(string name, string value)
    {
        var field = typeof(Localization).GetField(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (field == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Поля строкового ресурса с именем \"{0}\" не существует.", name));

        field.SetValue(null, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получает значение строкового ресурса по его имени
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Имя строкового ресурса</param>
    /// <returns>Значение строкового ресурса</returns>
    public static string GetString(string name)
    {
        var field = typeof(Localization).GetField(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (field == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Поля строкового ресурса с именем \"{0}\" не существует.", name));

        return field.GetValue(null) as string;
    }
}
```

Когда будет нужно, обращаемся к нужному полю класса и берем нужное значение. Если же строку нужно задать не с кода, а с редактора Unity, то передаем нужное имя поля, а в коде вызываем метод `Localozation.GetString(string name)`.

---

**Теперь самое интересное**

При первом запуске уровня все работает нормально. Но при перезапуске уровня случается вот такая дичь:

Запускаем отладку и видим, что с классом локализации и значениями полей все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пропускаем шаг отладки и видим, что, на самом деле, было передано "мусорное значение" строки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, это случается не просто при перезапуске уровня, но именно при перезапуске уровня, если на этот предмет уже кликали перед перезапуском уровня.

**Дальше больше**

Если вытаскивать значение полей с помощью рефлексии, то все нормально. А если обращаться к полям напрямую (через имя класса и имя поля), то там оказываются мусорные значения.

```
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestGarbageStrings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void DoTestFields()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.Append("\r\n" + Localization.downloading);

        builder.Append("\r\n" + Localization.play_game);
        builder.Append("\r\n" + Localization.settings);
        builder.Append("\r\n" + Localization.squad);

        //тут еще куча обращений к другим полям

        DialogBox.Instance
            .AddCancelButton("Ясно")
            .SetText(builder.ToString(), true)
            .SetSize(800, 600)
            .Show();
    }

    public void DoTestReflection()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        var fields = typeof(Localization).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var f in fields)
        {
            builder.Append("\r\n");
            builder.Append(f.GetValue(null));
        }

        DialogBox.Instance
            .AddCancelButton("Ясно")
            .SetText(builder.ToString(), true)
            .SetSize(800, 600)
            .Show();
    }
}
```

Если обращаться к полям на прямую(мусорные значения):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если брать значения с помощью рефлексии(правильные значения):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Хотя бы малейшие предположения. Возможно, кто то сталкивался с подобным (но такого и врагу не пожелаешь).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модификатор `readonly` подразумевает, что поле не будет меняться после создания объекта (или после вызова статического конструктора).

В связке со `static` это предположение разрешает JIT-у кэшировать значения в тех местах, где вы обращаетесь к полю. Или вообще кэшировать значения полей где-то глобально после первого обращения к ним. И даже убирать из кода `if`-ы, проверяющие значения полей - вобщем, JIT считает такие поля константами времени выполнения.

При просмотре через отладчик вы видите реальное значение поля. При вытягивании через reflection - тоже. А реально выполняется код, в который JIT вписал константный старый адрес. Потому что вы ему это явно разрешили.

Соответствующие оптимизации для `static readonly` были в основном CLR со времен 3.5, в Core - появились 2 года назад - [Treat readonly fields as JIT time constants](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1079). В mono (не уверен, на чем сейчас Unity работает) они скорее всего тоже есть.

Уберите `readonly` и все заработает. Скорее всего, т.к. минимального кода для воспроизведения проблемы в вопросе нет.

Comment: Как всегда, решение было ближе чем я думал. Пришлось, конечно, изменить поля на свойства, чтобы не нарушать логику класса. Хоть это и будет работать чуть медленней за счет вызовов методов, но хоть будет)

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI если свойства просто возвращают значение поля - медленее не станет - JIT инлайнит такие вызовы.

Comment: к сожалению, здесь согласиться не могу :(  Только что проверил, с помощью циклов и Stopwatch. Строка типа `имя += значение` гораздо быстрее выполняется если `имя` является полем, чем если `имя` это автоматически реализуемой свойство. Возможно, данный вопрос заслуживает отдельного поста и обсуждения?

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI производительность стоит замерять в release и через https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet. В debug с циклами и Stopwatch вы получите неверные результаты. Задайте вопрос - вдруг кто-то даст развернутый ответ.